# Enable NetworkManager in buildroot

Tags: networking, wifi, buildroot, networkmanager

I compiled a Buildroot environment for RPi 3 B+.
I have issues to enable NetworkManager.

I selected `BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE` and `wlan0` is found:

```
# nmcli dev status
DEVICE  TYPE       STATE                    CONNECTION 
lo      loopback   connected (externally)   lo
eth0    ethernet   unavailable              --
wlan0   wifi       unavailable              --
```

I checked if the driver is up:

```
# lsmod | grep brcmfmac
brcmfmac         270336  0
brcmutil          24576  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211         872448  1 brcmfmac
```

I'm aware to enable NetworkManager I can't handle the same interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  pre-up /etc/network/nfs_check
  wait-delay 15
  hostname $(hostname)
```

I have not `dhcpcd` package installed.
I tried with `ip link set wlan0 up` but it does nothing. But the interface is already up:

```
# iwconfig
lo      no wireless extension

eth0    no wireless extension

wlan0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
        Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated  Tx-Power=31 bDm
        Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
        Encryption key:off
        Power Management:on
```

What else I need in order to let NetworkManager to handle `wlan0`?

Comment: So, because dhcpcd isn't installed, NetworkManager doesn't work? If I'm wrong, what is causing Network manager not to work?

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 it's the opposite. I read that installing dhcpcd would prevent NM to work. Hence I verified I *don't* have it

Comment: Guys, even this time you want to close my question. PLEASE tell me what's wrong with it otherwise I cannot understand what you want from me. From my point of view, I showed the problem, my researches and my trials. And I asked a very specific question, not opinion-based and not wide.